# Firestore Database Offline Mode Broken

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, offline

We are having serious problems with Firestore Database offline mode in our app, and I am hoping we are just making a stupid mistake somewhere. Given that this is an absolute showstopper for us, any input would be greatly appreciated! Some details...

- We have several queries that are sub-second when on WiFi, but can take several **minutes** to return when offline.
- The queries do eventually return with correct data.
- These are very simple queries. Simply return all documents in a collection with a parent ID field matching a specific value.
- The result sets are very small. Sometimes only a few, and never more than 25 documents returned.
- It happens on several queries, so it does not seem to be specific to one type.
- It happens from both iOS and Android.
- We are using Xamarin and are using the Plugin.CloudFirestore library, which has worked well. While it is certainly possible to be related to the library, it seems doubtful given that the library is simply wrapping the native API calls.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out forcing 'source' to Cache when offline in GetDocument() fixes the issue. Our multi-minute queries are now down to sub-second. They are even faster than when connected now.

Comment: This is also happening to us. I dont understand why dont they check internet connectivity before attempting a request... It seems like a bad design decision to me.

Answer (score 0):

Offline queries can become slow when the offline cache grows large for a collection.  When that happens, queries can slow down, since the local device doesn't have anywhere near the ability of the Firestore cloud service to search many documents at massive scale.  Offline, you no longer get the guarantee of query performance scaling with the size of the result set.

Your options to work around this are:

- Disable persistence entirely
- Manually initialize a new Firebase app instance, set the size of its persistence cache to something management, and only use this app instance for the queries that can be slow
- Only perform this query while online, specifying a server source

Comment: Makes sense, but I don't think it applies to our case. Our cache is trivially small (unless Firestore is doing something silly). Is there a way to check current cache size?

This happens for a brand new user that has done nothing but create an account then relaunch the app without WiFi. I can't imagine we're talking more than a few K of data. The relaunch on WiFi takes about 200ms, without WiFi it takes 8 seconds.

Comment: I should add that offline functionality is critical for our app, so turning off persistence is not a viable option. And if persistence is just inherently 100x slower, then the feature seems pretty useless.

Comment: If you absolutely need fast offline queries, Firestore might not be the best choice for you.  Consider using a propert local database, and mirroring it to Firestore instead.  Firestore is not an offline-first system.  It's offline-also.

Comment: We are fine with slow queries offline. While we do need offline functionality, our app is definitely online first. But we do need to be able to run a trivial query to retrieve a handful of small objects offline in less than **2 minutes**. I can't possibly believe this is the intended functionality. Something must be wrong in my configuration or there is a thread blocking issue of some sort.

Comment: I just came across one of your articles online where you mention "server goes first, then cache" with a 10sec wait for connection before trying cache. Is this once per session, or for every read? If the latter, that could definitely explain our problem! Our reads are very small/trivial, but we have to perform several reads at launch. 

The Xamarin library (Plugin.CloudFirestore) does not seem to have the documentRef "source" option.

Comment: If that happened, you would see it in the log.

Comment: Well, I didn't see anything in the logs. But I did find the "source" param in Plugin.CloudFirestore, and that fixed it!!! Forcing source to Cache when offline cuts our **5 minute** launch queries down to ~1sec. Now faster than online launch! Thank goodness for your article!

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is not a "offline first" database, so it’s currently not optimized for handling large amounts of data locally, there are no indexes on cache, the speed depends on the device you're using, the size of your documents and the number of documents on your collection.

If found this article that might help you to optimize your queries offline: ["Why is my cloud firestore query slow"](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow-e081fb8e55dd), more specifically on the reason number two (*"Reason #2: Your offline cache is too big"*).

First it's important to know how offline mode works:

> ... when you query documents in your offline cache, Cloud Firestore
> needs to unpack every document stored locally for the collection being
> queried and compare it against your query. Or to put it another way,
> queries on the backend scale with the size of your result set, but
> locally, they kinda scale with the size of the data in the collection
> you’re querying.
>
> ...  if you have a lot of data in one single collection to sort
> through, or you’re just running on a slow device, local operations on
> a large offline cache can be noticeably slower.

This means in your specific case that it doesn't matter how many documents you're returning as a result of your offline query but rather how large the amount of data you're consulting, specially in the comment when you explained that you *"perform several reads at launch"*

Then the article  does a very good job explaining a few solutions to the specific problems, I will resume some of the points but I really recommend you to check the full article:

1. Add limits to your queries so you’re only retrieving the data that you think your users will need, and consider moving unneeded details into subcollections
2. Don’t stuff more data in the cache than you need.
3. Consider reducing the size of your offline cache. In this specific point I want to note that according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size) **the default cache size threshold is 40 MB and the minimum is 1 MB**, and this can be configured by modifying `cacheSizeBytes`

I hope that this information and recommendations help you to understand and resolve your problems with offline queries

Comment: The amount of data is trivial. Less than 1K per query. But there are as many as 30 queries. Apparently the problem was Firestore trying to hit the network first, waiting for a timeout (10 seconds?), then trying cache. 10 seconds x 30 queries is a serious problem. Forcing 'source' to be Cache when offline instantly fixed the problem. Our 5 minute launch is now down to less than 1 second. It is faster than online mode now! This should probably be better documented somewhere.

Comment: Good to know, I saw this information about trying to read/write first to the server on the video listed inside the [Access data offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)  documentation